# Tensorflow chatbot Questions Generation

Tags: python, tensorflow, chatbot, facebook-chatbot

What would be a good way to generation questions that a user has to answer in tensor flow???

for example, the system would ask the user a questions:

```
1. Is it large
```

and then take a users yes/no response:

```
Yes
```

account for all answers given and then predict what it is. (think 20 questions)

prediction:

```
Is it a cat?
```

I am using an LSTM and attempting to get this going.

so, what would be a good method for:

1. generating enough training data for this? (number of played iterations?)
2. generating the questions?
3. handing the user responses?

I feel like the accuracy will come. Just trying to get the behaviour down.

I think the problem I'm having is not really understanding the behaviour properly. it's annoying.

I need to work out how to generate the actual questions, and then take the users response to generate the next question.

looking at this, I need to create a **model** that gets passed into my **LSTMCell** and then generates the questions based on that.

Any advice would be good here.

Cheers, 
Glenn

Answer (score 2):

Concerning "creating enough training data": Here's an explanation how "the animal game" generates knowledge through user interaction. Looks like a long-term investment ;-) Maybe you can contact the creators and ask for the data.

http://www.animalgame.com/play/faq.php

Comment: I feel like the accuracy will come. Just trying to get the behaviour down.

I think the problem I'm having is not really understanding the behaviour properly. it's annoying. 

I need to work out how to generate the actual questions, and then take the users response to generate the next question. 

looking at this, I need to create a model that gets passed into my LSTMCell and then generates the questions based on that.